# Volume redering using Texture3D requires geometry.translate

Tags: three.js

I have a question regarding texture3D.
I am new to the 3D world. I was looking at volume rendering and came across this example https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl2_materials_texture3d.html

My question is about these three lines.

```
// line 119 - 122
// THREE.Mesh
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( volume.xLength, volume.yLength, volume.zLength );
geometry.translate( volume.xLength / 2 - 0.5, volume.yLength / 2 - 0.5, volume.zLength / 2 - 0.5 );

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

Why we need `geometry.translate`?

Suppose I change this example to use THREE.MeshBasicMaterial without the volume rendering just a static color, then I don't need any translation.

Can someone please explain why the `geometry.translate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a box of width 1, the left is at -0.5, and the right is at +0.5. This translation was necessary to change its range from `[-0.5, 0.5] => [0.0, 1.0]`. This way it's easier to sample the 3D texture with the position coordinates, since texture-sampling always requires coordinates between 0 - 1.